# css behavior on windows resize

Tags: jquery, css, sharepoint, fluid

THis is a sharepoint site. Working on the ribbon. I am prepending a couple of links right before the user menu on the right. On resizing the window to like halfway the menu links disappear. I would rather have the link text shorten to like a few letters but the whole menu still be there even after resizing window considerably. Like the "browse" and "page" tabs shrink, i want the similar behavior. How can we achieve that? is it even doable?
http://imageupload.org/en/file/239598/ss.jpg.html

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, yes this is doable but it is typically quite ugly on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, please refer to this chart http://sharepointexperience.com/csschart/csschart.html. It show's what you'll need to adjust in the css for each object.

For example here is the site actions attributes that you can customize:

[image]